# Is it considered safe to send an email without using SSL?

Tags: email, ssl, hosting, smtp, wordpress

I'm using a a plugin for Wordpress that allows you to configure outgoing email settings. The plugin works great. The PROBLEM is with my shared hosting account... it does not enable SSL.  When  new user registers for my site, an email is sent to them. I would prefer is this was over an SSL connection... is it ok if it's not using SSL?  Currently it is being sent via SMTP with authentication on port 25.

Answer (score 2):

Using SMTPS only protects the contents of the message until it gets to the server. Once it gets there, the MTA is allowed to take any action it likes upon the message, including but not limited to: folding, spindling, mutilation, and posting on the big computer-controlled billboard outside the data center.

If you have something truly important to say then encrypt the entire message using GnuPG or the like.

Comment: I think the point of SSL is to protect the user's password from being intercepted, not to protect the message contents. You could encrypt the message in GnuPG, but if you log in to the SMTP server without encryption, then anyone can see your e-mail password, which is potentially much worse than someone reading a single e-mail.